# rails return list of users with average rating above 5

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models User and Rating as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Each user receives multiple ratings from 1 - 10. I want to return all users with an average rating of > 5. I've got this so far...

```
User.joins(:ratings).where('rating > ?', 5)
```

But that code returns all Users with any rating above 5. I want Users with an Average rating above 5.

I've seen other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056954/how-to-efficiently-rate-and-retrieve-the-average-rating-of-a-model-in-rails) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339140/ruby-on-rails-order-users-based-on-average-ratings-with-most-reviews) are asking similar questions, but I'm having a brainfart today, and can't simulate their question into an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps someone in the future. This will find the average rating of each user through the ratings table, and return all users with an average rating above 5.

```
User.joins(:ratings).merge(Rating.group(:user_id).having('AVG(rating) > 5'))
```

.having was my missing link. More examples of .having [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at all users, why join first?

```
@avg = Ratings.group(:user_id).average("rating") #returns hash which contains arrays
@avg.each do |avg|                               #0 is user_id, 1 is value
  puts avg[0] if avg[1] > 5
end
```

Comment: Thanks man. That got me a lot a bit closer! `ids = Rating.group(:user_id).average("rating").select do |item, val| val > 5 end` then to find Users I do `User.where(id:ids.keys)` I feel like it's gotta be possible to do in just one statement, starting with User.

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined method average for user rating.

Check link below this is good example of moving float to average.

[How do I create an average from a Ruby array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341271/how-do-i-create-an-average-from-a-ruby-array)

Comment: I am torn, I visited that thread and it was really interesting. I learned quite a bit. But returning I do not see its applicability to the OPs question. It may be worthwhile expanding your answer.

Comment: Agreed, I don't have a ruby array. I've got a bunch of records with ratings 1-10 and an association to the User table. I want to return all Users with an average rating of greater than 5.